# Dependent DROP-DOWN selection using selenium and python

Tags: python, selenium

I have a form which has two drop-down menu say A and B. Contents of drop-down B is dependent on the selection of drop-down A.

The form uses AJAX to load the contents of drop down B.

I am using selenium and python to automatically select the drop down. I am able to select the drop down A but due to the use of AJAX my code is not working for selecting the content of drop-down B.

I have searched the selenium documentation (Explicit wait) and some stackoverflow answers but still I am unable to implement it in python. I am a newbie in python and selenium so please bear me.

Here is a small portion of my code :

```
#District selection DROP-DOWN A
district=Select(driver.find_element_by_id("ddlDistrict85"))
district.select_by_value("1")

#SRO selection DROP-DOWN B
# I Need EXPLICIT WAIT logic here to wait till the entire drop-down B is loaded
sro=Select(driver.find_element_by_id("ddlSRO85"))
sro.select_by_value("1")
```

Suggest some logic to wait till entire drop-down B is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [options](https://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.select.html#selenium.webdriver.support.select.Select.options) attribute from `Select` to check you have elements in the dropdown

```
district=Select(driver.find_element_by_id("ddlDistrict85"))
district.select_by_value("1")

sro=Select(driver.find_element_by_id("ddlSRO85"))
while len(sro.options) == 0:
    continue
sro.select_by_value("1")
```

Comment: @sakyan Can you check the size of  `sro.options` before and after the dropdown is filled? maybe there is some default values and the condition in the `while` should be `while len(sro.options) == 1` or more.

Comment: before loading the size of `sro.options` is 1. I tried by modifying your code but still it's not working.

Comment: @sakyan Care to share? :)

Comment: I got a solution, I am using `time.sleep(delay)` to wait the page to load the drop-down B.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't shared what the html looks like for these different menus, so let me assume that drop-down B is wrapped by a DIV with a specific class, or even better an ID, perhaps:

```
<div id="menuB"> ... </div>
```

Now, you could use [Expected Conditions](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/waits.html#explicit-waits) to wait for that menu to appear.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
element = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID,'menuB')))
```

Answer (score 0):

After searching a lot I found a simple solution where I am able to select the contents of drop-down B.
So I am answering my own question.

Use `sleep` function from `time` module to pause the execution of the program for some time(in seconds).

The program code would go like this :

```
import time #To import time module
#District selection
district=Select(driver.find_element_by_id("ddlDistrict85"))
district.select_by_value("1")
#SRO selection
time.sleep(5) 
sro=Select(driver.find_element_by_id("ddlSRO85"))
sro.select_by_value("1")
```

It's working now.

Comment: As a newbie, you will eventually discover that using hard coded sleeps is not reliable or robust, thus the availability of the WebDriverWait class.  I encourage you to go learn more about it, and experiment further with ExpectedConditions.  You will be much happier going forward!

Comment: Thanks @BreaksSoftware, I will surely try to explore more.